# How is Polly able to resend the same HTTP request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

An `HttpRequestMessage` can only be sent once. Attempting to resend it results in an `InvalidOperationException`.

So how is Polly able to circumvent this behavior, in other words, what's going on under the covers when using `AddPolicyHandler` with a Retry policy? I understand that it uses a `DelegatingHandler` but how is it able to process the same message multiple times?

Comment: Are you interested about the PolicyHttpMessageHandler's internals?

Comment: I suppose, but more in regards to the Retry policy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR: It has nothing to do with Polly.

---

Let's start with a single example which fails with an `InvalidOperationException` at the second attempt.

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://httpstat.us/500");

var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    result.StatusCode.Dump();
}
```

If we would move the request object creation inside the `for` loop then everything would be fine. But let's keep it outside of the `for`.

Let's create a simple delegating handler

```
public class RetryHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            "Retried".Dump();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and let's use it

```
var handler = new RetryHandler();
handler.InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://httpstat.us/500");

var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
result.StatusCode.Dump();
```

This version won't throw any `InvalidOperationException`.

---

So, why does the latter work and former doesn't?

The `InvalidOperationException` is thrown by the [`CheckRequestMessage`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/66ba9d5a66dd44762b780ca06dca1902c07b92aa/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L740) method of the `HttpClient`

```
private static void CheckRequestMessage(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    if (!request.MarkAsSent())
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.net_http_client_request_already_sent);
    }
}
```

This method is being called by the [`CheckRequestBeforeSend`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/66ba9d5a66dd44762b780ca06dca1902c07b92aa/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L559). And it is the very first command of the [`SendAsync`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/66ba9d5a66dd44762b780ca06dca1902c07b92aa/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L512). This public `SendAsync` calls its [`base's SendAsync`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/66ba9d5a66dd44762b780ca06dca1902c07b92aa/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L530). Here the `base` is a `HttpMessageInvoker` which [deals with the `HttpMessageHandler`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/66ba9d5a66dd44762b780ca06dca1902c07b92aa/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L136).

Long story short:

- If you want to reuse the `HttpRequestMessage` outside the `HttpClient` then it will fail at the second attempt due to the `CheckRequestMessage` call
- If you want to reuse the `HttpRequestMessage` inside a `DelegatingHandler` (`HttpMessageHandler`) then it won't fail because the `HttpMessageInvoker` [does not care](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/7222061f18b8342a0bd4edbd37df318fd43c47d3/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpMessageInvoker.cs#L66) about the reuse

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was wondering. Interesting mechanics there. Thanks for the detailed explanation, it makes much more sense now.